# Deploy ASP.NET Core API to Local IIS Error 500

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, iis

I'm having trouble with my app after deploying to my local IIS.
I've made an API using ASP.NET Core and I've run it on Visual Studio and it worked. It can do GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE requests. Then I wanted to deploy it to my local IIS. I've enabled my IIS features.
[image]
And I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG-6z4BQmRI&ab_channel=AspTricks.net 
When I run the application, it can run the WeatherForecast default application.
[image]
But when I run my API it gave me an error 500.
[image]
I've read Microsoft documentation and other tutorials and still doesn't work.
I think it doesn't work because it lost connection to the database, I'm using SQL Server for the database.
This is my project structure.
[image]
Side question, how do I remove the WeatherForecast default app, so it doesn't run that as default.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you solve your problem as I don't have enough information, but I can help you debug it. Your goal should be to find that exception that leads your api to respond with error 500. Lost connectivity to db could very well be it.

1st let me answer your second question. To remove the weather forecast, just right click and delete the:

1. WeatherForecast.cs
2. WeatherForecastController.cs
3. Any mention of those 2 that breaks your build after that.

#### Troubleshooting in windows and IIS

#### Event viewer

Two options here for you. The first one is to check your event viewer in the application folder

This is how: http://www.devtopics.com/how-to-check-the-application-event-log-for-errors/

#### Local debug

There is an option to debug your application on your local iis, as if you where running it through your IDE. Check how here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hi @AthanasiosKataras, anything I could provide you with to help me?

Comment: The exception itself with the message would be helpful.

Comment: I found this in the Event Viewer :
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\TestAPI'.

Comment: Hi, got that sorted out. Now a new error but still 500 : Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "TestDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Comment: You need to add the proper user to the application pool. Or use database credentials in your configuration file

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm